# Can't play minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I purchased Minecraft and went to play, but it told me I needed a Microsoft account. I logged into the Microsoft account that I had made, and it will only let me play the demo. What happened? Do I need to buy it again?

Comment: Is the purchase linked to the correct account?

Comment: I dont know i logged in after purchasing the game

Comment: It might say on the purchase receipt - you probably got an email

Comment: i never got an email.

Comment: @Zach Where is it saying you need a Microsoft account? On the website when you try to log in?

Comment: @Zach If you never got an email that confirms your purchase, and it isn't in your spam folder, you may have bought it under the wrong email or been scammed - might be good to verify that the email you purchased it under didn't have typos in it?

Comment: i bought it from the official minecraft website. I checked the spam folder too its not there